# How different are the JavaScript Constructor function and Scala constructor?

Tags: javascript, scala

I am new to Scala and still exploring this language with huge number of constructs and features.
Going by the way Class constructor's syntax is, it looks a lot similar to Constructor function in JavaScript.

Can anyone point out the similarities and the differences there are between the two.

Comment: "Constructor" functions in JavaScript are ad-hoc, while Scala's Constructor functions are an intentional language feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is not correct to compare Javascript and Scala in this case. Javascript is prototype based and dynamically typed, scala is statically typed and has classic inheritance model (+ multiple inheritance via traits).

So, similarity - constructor in both languages is used to initialize new instance of a class, the other - syntax, implementation, nuances - all the different. Scala has alternative contructors, JS - not, scala's constructor's parameters given on a class itself, in JS - it is a function which is called with `new` operator, etc.

Maybe you meant Java, not JavaScript?

Comment: I am not comparing the two languages at all.
JS is a lot diff than any other traditional object oriented language.
or the new ones.
What I was looking for was differences like : alternative constructors as u hv rightly mentioned.
My way of lookin at the similarity was from the the fact that there was one construct accepting params in both the cases and using them in all its member functions. 
JS doesnt hv class and Scala's constructor is blended into its class definition so they were looking the same to me.

Comment: Actually that blended constructor is just syntactic sugar for conciseness. It is treated as separate method.